# how to make control flow based on nullable variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullable

let say I have this variable

```
   val number : Int? = 12
```

I want to make control flow based on the variable, if the variable is null then do something, otherwise do something else

in Swift I can make something like this:

```
if let number = number {
    print(number)
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

I actually can do like this

```
if number != null {
   print(number!!) // I want to avoid exclamation mark like this
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

but I want to avoid exclamation mark, like in `print(number!!)`

I previously though that I can do something like this

```
number?.let {

print(it)

} else {
  // else block is not available in let in Kotlin
}
```

so how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?.` means it will be executed only if the left side is not null. 
The `?:` operator executes the right side only if the left side is not null.
You may have something like:

```
theExpression().toCompute().theNumber?.let { number ->
  print("This is my number $number
} ?: run {
  print("There is no number")
}
```

Here we use `T.let` extension function for the `then` clause and `run{ }` (extension) function for the `else` clause.

*Warning:* The semantics is that you expected to return `non-null` value from the `let {...}` closure to avoid the `run {..} closure from being executed. Thus the code like:
`number?.let { null } ?: run { 42 } === 42` (and not null)